# JNDI look up error using JBoss in JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jndi

I am trying to do JNDI lookup using JMS and JBoss for my practice application. 
But I am not able to figure out why it is not able to lookup.
I added entries into `destination-service.xml` for JBoss.
But as you can see my code in the images, its still giving me an error.

Is there any code part that I am missing or do I have to add some jar file to path or some other problem do you see after looking at my stacktrace for the error.

My Class
 [image: My Class]

destination-service.xml
[image: destination-service.xml]

Error
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't connect to the JNDI server at all.
Check host/port of the jndi server that you supply in the client code

As a 'self-check' I would also try to connect to any other object that resides in the JNDI tree, I think the exception will be the same :)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have used 
properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.provider.url", "localhost:1099"); in the code

Comment: Yes, but do you face this exception in line Context initialContext = QueryConsumer.getInitialContext() ? or it passes it and the exception occurs later?

Comment: It fetches the Context properly with values;
Exception is in   
QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

Comment: In this case you should revise the name of the "ConnectionFactory" I guess. Take a look at JNDI tree mbean in the jmx console and find your object - may be it was deployed under the other name.

Comment: I checked out the the JNDI name for the application, it was "/queue/Anuj" I replaced the same in the code and ran the code (only diff was '/') but to no avail, did not run :(

Comment: |   +- Anuj (class: org.jboss.jms.destination.JBossQueue) was listed under service=JNDIView

Answer (score 0):

> When you start jboss, use "run.sh -b 0.0.0.0". By default, jboss is secure and bound to localhost only.

Maybe [this](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=49698#255218) will help you.

Comment: yes this maybe the cause, but I am running jboss from eclipse, how can i enter that bash command ? there must be something equivalent of that to be entered in some config file for jboss i think....